# i have multiple input elements and i want one ng-model for them all

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple input elements and I want one ng-model for them all, but when I use the model with ng-show it is not that sensitive , so how can I go .

```
<form ng-model="yes">
<input type="checkbox">1</input>
<input type="checkbox">2</input>
<input type="checkbox">3</input>
</form>
```

i.e I have multiple checkboxes and I want them all ticked to show another element

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Are you trying to implement multiple checkbox functionality?

Comment: i have multiple checkbox and I want them all ticked to show another element

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "sensitive"?
This should work if you want to set boolean properties:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="myModel.prop1" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input ng-model="myModel.prop2" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input ng-model="myModel.prop3" type="checkbox" value="1">
</form>
```

But if you mean different options for one model you have to use radio buttons:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="myModel.prop1" type="radio" value="1">
  <input ng-model="myModel.prop1" type="radio" value="2">
  <input ng-model="myModel.prop1" type="radio" value="3">
</form>
```

You can debug your model by putting {{myModel}} somewhere in the source code, so you will see immediately the effect of your changes

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form name="myForm">
        <input ng-model="myModel1" type="checkbox">Option A <br/>
        <input ng-model="myModel2" type="checkbox">Option B <br/>
        <input ng-model="myModel3" type="checkbox">Option C <br/>
        <div ng-show="(myModel1 && myModel2 && myModel3)">ABC</div>
    </form>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ygDyiSYXftljXDJew8mN)